# How to programatically add and remove view from Fragment

Tags: java, android, layout, view, fragment

I want to have two `.xml` layout files for a Fragment conditionally I want to launch one and change to other on some event, tried searching Javadoc to find relevant methods, any pointers would be helpful

Comment: use a ViewAnimator or directly call ViewGroup.addView*() / ViewGroup.removeView[At]()

Comment: @pskink Great thank you I was looking for this, however when I try to remove MapView it keeps gray square and on touch of that square it gets removed, any idea how to refresh view

Comment: you use ViewAnimator or add/remove views directly? also if you run it on the emulator try hierarchyviewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create two classes that `extends Fragment` class and `override onCreateView()` method and inflate your layout. ex:

Class **FragmentOne.java**

```
   public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       //Inflate the layout for this fragment

      return inflater.inflate(
              R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);


      }
    }
```

Class **FragmentTwo.java**

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // Inflate the layout for this fragment

  return inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);


 }
}
```

And in your **MainActivity.java**

```
    Fragment fr;

         if(view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
             fr = new FragmentTwo();

         }else {
             fr = new FragmentOne();
         }

         FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
         fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: can i change it after creation ?

Comment: yes you can add the MainActivity code where ever you need to implement.

Comment: thank you, I am using swipable view http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ what I want is for first tab I want to have 3 step process and second tab should be step less, I see your point of putting Fragment into MainACtivity but I don't know how can I integrate it in this example

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public class FragmentCont extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   //Inflate the layout for this fragment
   if(condition1){
    return inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
   }else{
    return inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
   }


  }
}
```

Comment: can i change it after creation ?

Comment: after creation, u have to change it in activity.Have a frame layout in activity and replace it using fragment manager as done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849490/android-adding-fragments-dynamically